# Why is my program returning a garbage value when k == 0 in the for-loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, garbage, cmath

This is a simple C++ program which computes f(x) using a formula for a fixed number of values between 2 given numbers.

There seems to be some problem when k = 0 in the for loop. It is returning a garbage value.

Can anyone tell me why?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

  int const POINTS = 21;
  double const PI = 3.1416;
  double min, max, increment, dataPoints[21];

  cout << "Enter max value: ";
  cin >> max;

  cout << "Enter min value: ";
  cin >> min;

  increment = (max - min) / (POINTS - 1);


  cout << setw (20) << "X-Value" << "|";
  cout << setw (20) << "Y-Value" << endl;

  double k;
  int l;

  for (k = min, l = 0; l < POINTS, k <= max; l++, k += increment)
    {
      dataPoints[l] = (PI / 16) * sin (6.036 * k) + (1 / 64) * PI * cos (24.44 * k);
      cout << setw (20) << k << setw (20) << dataPoints[l] << endl;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Enter max value: 4
Enter min value: -4
             X-Value|             Y-Value
                  -4            0.164018
                -3.6          -0.0507715
                -3.2          -0.0881608
                -2.8            0.182492
                -2.4           -0.184497
                  -2           0.0931637
                -1.6           0.0453027
                -1.2            -0.16085
                -0.8            0.195021
                -0.4           -0.130529
       -5.55112e-016       -6.57901e-016
                 0.4            0.130529
                 0.8           -0.195021
                 1.2             0.16085
                 1.6          -0.0453027
                   2          -0.0931637
                 2.4            0.184497
                 2.8           -0.182492
                 3.2           0.0881608
                 3.6           0.0507715
                   4           -0.164018

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.634 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: This happens because of computers are counting in binary numbers. This means small additions and subtractions can be ever so slightly different from the expected value. If you round it or cut the numbers beginning from the idk fifth place behind the . you should be fine

Comment: [tangent] `l < POINTS, k <= max` doesn't work how you think. The result of one of these comparisons is thrown away. You likely meant `l < POINTS && k <= max`

Comment: [Pro Tip] Don't use a floating point type as a loop index.  If you want to step by four tenths then you would do something like `for (int index = start_value * 10, index < stop_value * 10; index += 4) { divide index by 10 here to get the decimal number }`

Comment: by the way, `std::` namespace contains `min` and `max` names, technically it's an UB to use that in this case. You're lucky not including `<algorithm>` (it's not defined if any of the headers won't) while using namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem problem lies in the code `(1 / 64)` ... because you have put this expression in brackets. It is, thus, **integer** division and, as such, will *always* have the value of **zero**.

Try this, instead:

```cpp
    dataPoints[l] = (PI / 16) * sin (6.036 * k) + (1.0 / 64) * PI * cos (24.44 * k);
```

There is also a problem in the way you have expressed the 'test' condition in your `for` loop - the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) here will, effectively, ignore the first part of the expression:

```cpp
for (k = min, l = 0; l < POINTS, k <= max; l++, k += increment)
```

For safety, when you want **both** conditions to be tested, use the `&&` operator:

```cpp
for (k = min, l = 0; l < POINTS && k <= max; l++, k += increment) {
```

Lastly, your *actual* question:

> There seems to be some problem when k = 0 in the for loop. It is
>   returning a garbage value.

No, it's not! The floating-point operations you perform on the `k` variable (i.e. `k += increment`, on each loop) are not precise: what you think will be `0.4 + (-0.4)` will *actually* be `'nearly' '0.4' - 'nearly' '0.4'`; as such, the value you get (my system gives `-5.55112e-16`) is a 'reasonable approximation' to zero, given the ranges of the numbers that you've used (and the accumulated 'errors' in the previous loops).

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Ooh very nice. I didn't even notice the comma in the loop condition, good catch. The one other thing I'd say to add is the solution to printing `k` and having it look like they want (which is probably a `round()`). But it all looks good to me! Nice edits :)

Comment: Aha! Comments as critique - working as they were intended! I much appreciate the input!

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you for the explanation! I fixed the test condition in the for loop and I used setprecision(1) << fixed << k; to display k. It seemed to have worked, however, I'm not sure if it's the actual fix or if I'm missing something.

Comment: @Vaibav79 No, I don't *think* you have missed anything - just remember that floating-point data in computers can only ever approximate real world values. Just don't try using any comparisons of the form, `if (k == 0)` or they are likely to fail.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because of rounding error when you increment by 0.2, your k value never gets to be *exactly* zero -- its off by a little bit.  See [What every computer scientist should know about floating point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)